# Decode a pickled file that has been encoded as a Blob

Tags: javascript, python, flask, pickle

#### Overview:

I am trying to get save/load functionality working as part of a web app I am building, but cannot properly reload a file after I've downloaded it.

#### Backend:

I have a list a of lists in python that looks something like

`[[bytes, bytes, int, list, list, str], [...], [...], etc]`.

This is the data I care about. I then pickle it using

```
with open(file_path, 'wb') as fp:
   pickle.dump(save_this_arr, fp)
```

and send it using Flask's send_file:

`return send_file(file_path, as_attachment=True)`

#### Frontend:

On the front end, I am creating a blob, encoding a data url, and then setting it as the src of a hidden `<iframe>`:

```
let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
self.downloader.src = url
```

This works fine and gets me a file that I can re-upload.

#### Problem:

I am getting stuck on how to properly decode the URL so that I can pickle.load the result. The two links below seem like they're what I need, but I'm getting UnicodeDecodeErrors when I apply it to my code.

#### Current Attempt:

```
with open(file_path, "rb") as fid:
     contents = fid.read()
data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(contents, encoding='utf-16')
with open(file_path, 'wb') as fid:
    fid.write(text)
with open(file_path, 'rb') as fid:
    myList = pickle.load(fid)
```

#### EDIT:

The original question asked about decoding a url because I misunderstood what `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` was doing. From [this blog post](https://chrisrng.svbtle.com/using-url-createobjecturl), I realized that we are actually creating a reference to an in-memory blob. So what I actually want to do is read a Blob in Python.

#### References:

[Url decode UTF-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python/16566128#16566128)

[decoding URL encoded byte stream data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105063/decoding-url-encoded-byte-stream-data-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I was unable to decode the blob directly, but encoding to a base64 string before writing the file works.

#### Backend (writing to disk):

```
import base64
with open(file_path, 'wb') as fp:
    data = pickle.dumps(save_this_arr)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
    fp.write(encoded)
```

#### Frontend (copied from question - no change):

```
let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
self.downloader.src = url
```

#### Backend (reading from disk):

```
with open(file_path, "rb") as fid:
    contents = fid.read()
    decoded = base64.b64decode(contents)
    myList = pickle.loads(decoded)
```